# How do you connect as a Snowflake Reader Account from Python?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, reader

Snowflake Python Connector only works for a user created with CREATE USER command, doesn't seem to work for managed reader accounts.

On WebUI:

```
CREATE MANAGED ACCOUNT python_reader_acct ADMIN_NAME = reader_1, ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'reader_pwd', TYPE = READER;
```

On Python:

```
import snowflake.connector
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='reader_1',
    password='reader_pwd',
    account='xxxx.ca-central-1.aws',
    <....>)
```

will give credential error:
snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: *****.ca-central-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.

Snowflake's documentation only mentions creating and dropping reader accounts, not much in the way of granting permissions to readers or connecting as readers.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake Reader Accounts are just like regular accounts after they are created, except for the limitations on executing DML statements as described in the documentation.  So, once you've created the reader account, you should be able to log into it with your user/password.  However, you should've gotten a license-plate type of account name.  In your example above, is `xxxx` the reader account or the account that you ran the `CREATE MANAGED ACCOUNT` from?

Also, can you clarify whether you were able to log into the reader account via the Snowflake UI?  Shouldn't be any different from Python, but might help you diagnose your issue.

Comment: Thanks Mike. `xxxx` was the provider account that ran `CREATE MANAGED ACCOUNT` so I replaced it with the reader account and the credential error is gone. The new error is _Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed_. And this was my other question - how do I grant permission?

 `GRANT ROLE reader_role TO USER reader_1` throws error: reader_1 does not exist or not authorized.

Can't login as reader via Snowflake UI (incorrect user/pwd error). Tried both reader account name (`python_reader_acct`) and user name (`reader_1`) as well as both provider/reader accounts on the URL.

Comment: Raj - the Reader account is a brand new account.  You need to add users and roles to the new reader account, grant permissions to those roles, etc.  Have you done all of that?  It is no different from your provider account in that regard, but it is a completely separate account.